# Prokaryotes Genome

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics

1. What function of repetitive sequences of Prokaryote?
2. I see a gap (intergenic region) between 2 coding strand. But just only a single origin region in Prokaryotes. How it can transcription coding strands after the intergenic region?
3. I read documents say the genome of Prokaryote is small. So it needs to overlapping transcription in a chromosome. How its works with a single origin region?

Comment: A google search resulted in finding this site, which I believe explains a lot about the prokaryotic genome: https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-microbiology/chapter/prokaryotic-genomes/

Comment: An additional resource for making sure you understand the basics of biology is [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/). The reason I'm suggesting that site is because your questions reveal that you are confused about some the difference between transcription and replication. ——— Please also take the time to take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 